# How can I get entries for a given time period from a 400MB+ log file?

Tags: files, logs, text, filter

I have a 400MB+ Tomcat log file (`catalina.out`). How can I pull out entries for a given time period?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this would work well for your 400MB file, but here are some CLI one liners that would do the trick.

If you're looking for entries for a specific date, `grep -c` can probably do what you need.

Otherwise, you could probably use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/date1/,/date2/p' filename
```

For example with an input file "test":

```
Day 0: foo
Day 1: hello
Day 2: world
Day 3: blah
```

You could run

```
[me@mybox tmp]$ sed -n '/Day 1/,/Day 2/p' test
Day 1: hello
Day 2: world
```

Comment: This will output nothing if no line contains the start date and will output until the end of file if no line contains the end date. The absence of a date may be caused by server down, no event or log rotation. So I would not count on every date's presence.

Comment: True, but this is about as simple as you can get without parsing the dates and figuring out when you've crossed. My assumption was that with a 400MB log files, rotation might not be an issue and there's probably events close to your area of interest.  For the rotation problem at least, there's always `cat`, `zcat`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Consider using tools such as [splunk](http://www.splunk.com), [loglogic](http://www.loglogic.com/), [logrhythm](http://logrhythm.com/), [graylog2.org(opensource)](http://graylog2.org/)